# Favorites menu placing dot next to wrong icon

Tags: 18.04, .desktop, desktop-icons, favorites

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

On the left of the screen is the column of favorites icons to start various applications. I have an icon there for the Brave Browser, and another icon for the Dissenter Browser (which is based on Brave). I've put the files **brave-browser.desktop** and **dissenter-browser.desktop** in my `~/.local/share/applications` directory. I've tested to make sure it is using the files in that directory by temporarily changing the Name fields.

When an application is started, the system displays a small dot next to the icon for the application that is running. When I click on the Dissenter icon, it starts the correct application but places the dot next to the Brave icon instead of the Dissenter icon.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

**brave-browser.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Brave Web Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Access the Internet
iExec=/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=brave-browser
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=application/pdf;application/rdf+xml;application/rss+xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xhtml_xml;application/xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;image/webp;text/html;text/xml;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=New Incognito Window
Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable --incognito
```

**dissenter-browser.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Dissenter Web Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Access the Internet
Exec=/usr/bin/dissenter-browser
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=dissenter-browser
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=application/pdf;application/rdf+xml;application/rss+xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xhtml_xml;application/xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;image/webp;text/html;text/xml;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/usr/bin/dissenter-browser-stable

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=New Incognito Window
Exec=/usr/bin/dissenter-browser-stable --incognito
```

Comment: Please post the full contents of **brave-browser.desktop** and **dissenter-browser.desktop**.

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver I checked, Ubuntu sees both as the same application in some manner, in spite of the contents of `.desktop` files.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the contents of those two files. The site would not allow me to include foreign language unicode characters so I had to remove those lines. However, since they are just translations of the Name field, they probably aren't where the problem is. Everything else in those files is now included in my original question.

Comment: Is the `iExec` in **brave-browser.desktop** a typo?

Comment: @Zephyrus Also, would you please post a cropped screenshot showing the dot next to the wrong application icon?